# Trouble Registering Next.js 13.4 Service Worker

Tags: reactjs, next.js, progressive-web-apps

I am currently developing a PWA using Next.js version 13.4.19. However, I am facing an issue where everything else, such as the manifest, is registering, but the service worker is not. Does anyone know the reason for this issue?

this is my layout.tsx

```js
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import React from "react";
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
  title: 'asdasdasdas',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
  manifest: '/manifest.json',
  themeColor: "#3558f6",
}
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

and my config

```js
const runtimeCaching = require('next-pwa/cache')
const withPWA = require('next-pwa')({
  dest: 'public',
  register: true,
  skipWaiting: true,
  sw: "/sw.js",
  runtimeCaching: [
    {
      urlPattern: "/",
      handler: 'NetworkFirst',
      options: {
        cacheName: 'pages-cache',
      },
    },
  ]
});

const nextConfig = withPWA({
  reactStrictMode: true,
});
module.exports = nextConfig;
```

I have checked the "Application" tab within the developer tools.

[image]
[image]

I have also confirmed that the cache for my website is not being stored.

How can I resolve this issue? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look in your "public" folder to see if the sw.js file exists, when you run the build by doing "npm run build".
And I think you can remove the line "sw:"/sw.js".